# Is it possible to override a class method so it is accessed by an inherited method in the inherited class?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, overriding

the formulation of the question is probably tricky and not very clear, but this is what I mean:

I have a base class called `Node`. This class offers multiple methods that are relevant for any inherited class. My idea was to use a common structure and simply override the constructor and specific methods in the inherited classes.

```
class Node{
    uint node_id;
    Node(uint id); // Constructor
    callback(); // Callback method
    process(); // Process method
}
```

```
class Modified_Node: public Node{
    uint node_id;
    Modified_Node(uint id): Node(id); // New constructor reusing the base constructor
    process(); // New process function
}
```

The problem here is that the `callback` method has to call the `process` method. My idea was to inherit the class and simply override the `process` method, hoping it would make the `callback` method call the new `process`.

```
void callback(){
    do_something();
    process();
    return;
}
```

I've realized that `callback` is still calling the original `process` method in the template class. It makes sense as I'm not reinstantiating the `callback` method in any sense but I don't know what is the best way to do this, is it necessary to redefine the function `callback` completely or is there any way to do this elegantly? To clarify, the code in the `callback` method is exactly the same.

I've tried to modify the new class, changing the relevant methods, in this case `process`, in order to make the base method `callback` call the overridden method instead of the original without any luck.

Comment: Are you looking for virtual functions? https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/virtual-functions/

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for the chapter(s) covering polymorphism in [a good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: *"I have a template class"* -- this might be a poor choice of words, since it is similar to "[class template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template)", which is often used for nodes, but is not what you have here.

Comment: I agree with @JaMiT.  What you have there is a _base_ class.

Comment: @BoP, that's it, I guess declaring it as virtual solves my problem, I'll give it a try. thanks